# PROC MI not Returning matching results between 9.2 and 9.4

Tags: sas

When running identical code between two versions of SAS (9.2 WIN and 9.4 Linux), I'm noticing that the results are differing between the two versions.  Specifically imputed values are not matching.

I know that once in a while SAS likes to restructure PROCS and their options but I wasn't able to find any updates to this PROC in online documentation.  Would anyone know if the syntax below is still valid in 9.4?  Note the use of MONOTONE and predictive mean matching to impute missing values.

```
proc mi data=mitemp out=miout seed=37951 noprint nimpute=1;
  class trt01pn coungr1n sexn;
     Monotone regpmm;
  VAR trt01pn coungr1n sexn ulc2 ulc3 ulc4 ulc5 ulc6 ulc7 ulc8 ulc9;;
  by _imputation_;
run;
```

Comment: SAS usually backwards compatible.  Only if old results or methods were incorrect will new results differ.  This is a question for SAS Tech Support.  http://support.sas.com

Comment: Thanks @DomPazz, I'm reaching out to SAS Tech Support in addition to posting here.  I was hoping for an easy answer, but if I get an answer from SAS first, I will definitely post the reply here.

Comment: In SAS/STAT 14.1 they definitely made changes to the NIMPUTE option, not sure if that means it should give different results. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_whatsnew_sect027.htm